# How can I print a large image to multiple pages on mac os?

Tags: printing, printer, images, scaling

I have a large png image. I want to print it to pdf with paper size 8.5x11 across multiple pages - the image should be scaled up to fit the paper width and since the image is tall, it should be split onto multiple pages.

I tried doing it in Preview but it doesn't want to print it across multiple pages.

[image]

Is there a way to do it using some other tool or the command-line?

Update: Looks like microsoft paint in Windows has this feature (https://scottiestech.info/2009/08/08/how-to-easily-print-a-large-image-to-multiple-pages-in-windows/)

Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: Have you try to scale to 100%?

Comment: It may be easier for you to select a portion, perhaps the top third, copy to another picture, paste, and print that.  Repeat for the other sections of the picture.  If you're working from MacOS Preview, you can use the x,y coordinates on the selector to ensure that you don't miss any of the original document.

Comment: Rasterbator will do that:  https://www.wikihow.com/Print-a-Large-Image-on-Multiple-Pages-on-PC-or-Mac